# Finding CDF of a continuous PDF given by $f(x,y)=8xy$ for $0\leq x \leq y\leq 1$

Tags: probability

Does it matter how I set up the limits of integration to find the CDF.
Is this correct:

$F(x,y)=\int_0^x\int_0^y8uv$ $dudv=2x^2y^2$

Answer (score 2):

No.  The PDF is only $8xy$ for $0 \le x \le y \le 1$ (and presumably $0$ everywhere else). Draw a picture before integrating.  It will be different 
for $x \le y$ than for $y \le x$ (and you need to consider both cases).

EDIT: Here is the picture in the case $0 \le x \le y \le 1$.  You want to integrate over the part of the blue region inside the rectangle.

[image]

Comment: I can't find an example anywhere on how to do this

Comment: I'm wondering in this case is my answer correct

Comment: As I told you, your answer is not correct.